# how to change docker source of the context of the build

Tags: docker

Dockerfile is:

```
FROM nginx
COPY html /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Dockerfile is in pwd directory(which is home/ubuntu/app), when use following command:

```
docker build -t mynginx .
```

I was giving an error:

copy failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder344/html: no such file or directory.

how to change docker source of the context of the build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker build only look files in Dockerfile file context, mean the build will copy `/home/ubuntu/app/` from this location where your Dockerfile is.

So better to place your `html` the `/home/ubuntu/app` in this location as docker build send tar of the context to docker daemon so it is recommended to keep the context minimal.

Answer (score 1):

`docker build -t mynginx .` would expect to find Dockerfile in the current directory. Moreover, relative paths used by Dockerfile instructions would be relative to the current directory.

You can set the build context path to a different path `docker build -t mynginx [some_folder_path]`. Docker would search for Dockerfile there. You can modify the path to Dockerfile using `-f` option `docker build -f [path_to_dockerfile] -t mynginx [some_folder_path]`

Answer (score 0):

There may be a work around if you use vscode -

install the docker extension and open it

in the explorer you will see a drop down menu for context - see below

[vscode docker context drop down menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mz4vQ.png)